# Craco not supporting react-scripts v. 5 - alternatives?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, craco

We're hoping to get our projects using [react-scripts v 5](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/react-scripts), and based on [recent comments from the maintainers of craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/issues/378#issuecomment-1108663751), a new version with support for the newest version of CRA won't be coming soon (except in the alpha version), if at all.

Our craco.config isn't doing that much heavy lifting - we use it to have webpack ignore [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) files, [limit timezone data used by moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin), and [transpile .less files for antd](https://github.com/DocSpring/craco-antd) (we don't plan on using antd forever, but for now we have some of their components in our app).

I'm curious, what are other people doing now that craco is going the way of the [Italian town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craco)?

Comment: CRACO is back! maybe https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/426

Answer (score 1):

Its better to migrate to [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) since 'CreateReactApp' along with `react-scripts` itself is dead and not even supported by React now.

No need to use tools like Craco with vite.